# PowerShell - lowercase text between two characters

Tags: powershell, character, between, lowercase

I have a lot of .txt files where I need to lowercase content in between two characters - after "%" and before ";".

The code below makes all content in the files lowercase and I need it to only do it in all instances between the two characters as mentioned.

```
$path=".\*.txt"
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | foreach{    
    (Get-Content $_.FullName).ToLower() | Out-File $_.FullName
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here an example using *regex* replace with a callback function to perform the lowercase:

```
$path=".\*.txt"
$callback = {  param($match) $match.Groups[1].Value.ToLower() }
$rex = [regex]'(?<=%)(.*)(?=;)'

Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
        $rex.Replace((Get-Content $_ -raw), $callback) | Out-File $_.FullName
}
```

**Explanation**:

The regex uses a positive lookbehind to find the position of `%` and a lookahead for the position of `;` and caputes everything between in a group:

[image]

The caputred group gets passed to the `callback`function which invokes `ToLower()` on it.

Comment: beautiful implementation Martin

Comment: @RanadipDutta Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I am so much fascinated with the callback function. It looks so awesome the way it has been implemented.

Comment: It works in most cases but when there is a line break in the text file between the "%" and ";" it doesn't change the text to lowercase. Is there a solution to that?

Comment: If you change the regex to: `(?s)(?<=%)(.*)(?=;)` it should work. Please consider to accept the answer.

Comment: Thank You very much for the answers. They are really helpful. I've found that in some instances I need to lowercase only the string/word right next to the "%"-character. For example %WORD1 WORD2 Bla Bla; where I need to lowercase only "word1". Can You help with a solution to that?